# Python, converting int to str, trailing/leading decimal/zeros

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I convert my dataframe values to str, but when I concatenate them together the previous ints are including trailing decimals.

```
df["newcol"] = df['columna'].map(str) + '_' + df['columnb'].map(str) + '_' + df['columnc'].map(str)
```

This is giving me output like
`500.0` how can I get rid of this leading/trailing decimal? **sometimes my data in column a will have non alpha numeric character**s.

```
+---------+---------+---------+------------------+----------------------+
| columna | columnb | columnc |     expected     |  currently getting   |
+---------+---------+---------+------------------+----------------------+
|         |      -1 |      27 | _-1_27           | _-1.0_27.0           |
|         |      -1 |      42 | _-1_42           | _-1.0_42.0           |
|         |      -1 |      67 | _-1_67           | _-1.0_67.0           |
|         |      -1 |      95 | _-1_95           | _-1.0_95.0           |
| 91_CCMS |   14638 |      91 | 91_CCMS_14638_91 | 91_CCMS_14638.0_91.0 |
| DIP96   |    1502 |      96 | DIP96_1502_96    | DIP96_1502.0_96.0    |
| 106     |   11694 |     106 | 106_11694_106    | 00106_11694.0_106.0  |
+---------+---------+---------+------------------+----------------------+
```

Error:

`invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

Comment: Please provide 5-10 rows of your columns along with your expected output. Thanks.

Comment: What does `df['columnb'].tolist()` output?

Comment: I get name "df" is not defined.

Comment: Huh? Isn't that the name of your dataframe variable? You've indicated as such in your question?!

Comment: sorry, my mistake, I am getting `'function' object is not subscriptable` when I run `df['columnb'].tolist()` in my console, along with calling my function prior.

Comment: That means you assigned `df` to something that's _NOT_ your DataFrame. You're making this challenging to debug ;/

Comment: How about we try this: `df['newcol'] = df.astype({'columnb': 'int', 'columnc': 'int'}).filter(like='column').astype(str).agg('_'.join, axis=1)` it should solve your problem.

Comment: I am getting error, `invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`  for your `filter(like='column'` should this be column a?

Comment: The answer will depend on the data, and I don't think I should go on giving you more increasingly complex answers especially when none of those errors manifest in the sample data provided. Good luck.

Comment: i am wondering if it is because some of my data may have '_' 's in them, Ie columna data could have underscores in that column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**:
If your `df` has more than 3 columns, and you want to join only 3 columns, you may specify those columns in the command using columns slicing. Assume your `df` has 5 columns named as : `AA`, `BB`, `CC`, `DD`, `EE`. You want only joining columns `CC`, `DD`, `EE`. You just need to specify those 3 columns before the `fillna`, and assign the result to `newcol` as you want:

```
df["newcol"] = df[['CC', 'DD', 'EE']].fillna('') \
                   .applymap(lambda x: x if isinstance(x, str) else str(int(x))).agg('_'.join, axis=1)
```

*Note: I just break command into 2 lines using `'\'` for easy reading.*

---

**Original**:
I guess your real data of `columna`  `columnb`  `columnc` contain `str`, `float`, `int`, empty space, blank space, and maybe even `NaN`.

`Float` with decimal values = .00 in a column dtype `object` will show without decimal.

Assume your `df` has only 3 columns: `colmna`, `columnb`, `columnc` as you said. Using command below will handle: `str`, `float`, `int`, `NaN` and joining 3 columns into one as you want:

```
df.fillna('').applymap(lambda x: x if isinstance(x, str) else str(int(x))).agg('_'.join, axis=1)
```

---

I created a sample similar as yours

```
   columna columnb columnc
0               -1      27
1      NaN      -1      42
2               -1      67
3               -1      95
4  91_CCMS   14638      91
5    DIP96              96
6      106   11694     106
```

Using your command returns the concatenated string having '.0' as you described

```
df['columna'].map(str) + '_' + df['columnb'].map(str) + '_' + df['columnc'].map(str)

Out[1926]:
0          _-1.0_27.0
1       nan_-1.0_42.0
2          _-1.0_67.0
3          _-1.0_95.0
4    91_CCMS_14638_91
5           DIP96__96
6       106_11694_106
dtype: object
```

Using my command:

```
df.fillna('').applymap(lambda x: x if isinstance(x, str) else str(int(x))).agg('_'.join, axis=1)

Out[1927]:
0              _-1_27
1              _-1_42
2              _-1_67
3              _-1_95
4    91_CCMS_14638_91
5           DIP96__96
6       106_11694_106
dtype: object
```

Comment: thank you andy, where do I input my column headers?

Comment: You mean your df has more columns than 3 so you need to specify which column to join? If so,  check update. I added explanation

Comment: @excelguy: I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't reproduce this error but maybe you could try something like:

```
df["newcol"] = df['columna'].map(lambda x: str(int(x)) if isinstance(x, int) else str(x)) + '_' + df['columnb'].map(lambda x: str(int(x))) + '_' + df['columnc'].map(lambda x: str(int(x)))
```

Comment: hey thanks for your reply, i am getting this error `invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

Comment: i am wondering if it is because some of my data may have '_' 's in them, Ie columna data could have underscores in that column.

Comment: ok i added the `if x else ""` part, getting new error `invalid literal for int() with base 10: '9_CCMS'`

Comment: Same error :(, I even put your if else condition for all columns.  `invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'HDGG'`